Can't find 14.65.0.1 version for packages Microsoft.Portal.Extensions.Hubs and Microsoft.Portal.Tools pakages in visual studio
I Can't find 14.65.0.1 version for packages
Microsoft.Portal.Extensions.Hubs and Microsoft.Portal.Tools pakages in visual studio
I want to upgrade Microsoft.Portal.Extensions.Hubs and Microsoft.Portal.Tools packages to version 14.65.0.1, but the packages version not contain this version

Have you tried any other approach so far? @jing

As mentioned here in the blog, if you are trying to upgrade the Microsoft.Portal.Extensions.Hubs and tools packages you can go to Manage NuGet packages under Tools section in visual studio and check the 14.65.0.1 version in updates.

If you are not able to upgrade it, check the available versions in nuget.org and make sure that it is enabled in visual studio properly.
If the required version is not listed, it means that the version is not supported in the NuGet package repository.
You can be able to view the versions after selecting a specific NuGet package as shown below.
Path: Manage NuGet package >> Browse >> Search for a package

Also update the NuGet package by self   as it restores and updates the NuGet versions so that it will be automatically restores the NuGet packages.
nuget.exe update -self
Note: If either of the above doesn't work, check for the available versions of the package and upgrade it to the latest releases.
